# Angular 2 two-way binding for a complex type for custom component

Tags: angular, paging

I'm trying to create a paging component, so that in my lists I won't need to repeat a lot of code. I'm also using Angular 2 in ES5 flavor. Thus here's my code:

```
app.pagingComponent = ng.core.Component({
        templateUrl: '/pathToPagingHtml',
        selector: 'paging',
        inputs: ['listParameters']
    }).Class({
        constructor: function() {
        }
    });
```

And here's how I use it:

```
<paging [listParameters]="listParameters"></paging>
```

And of course I'm about to improve it into two-way data binding (banana in the box syntax) as follow:

```
<paging [(listParameters)]="listParameters"></paging>
```

But as I change `listParameters` in the parent component, nothing changes inside the child component, which has an interplation syntax in the template HTML.
Please note that `listParameters` is an object, not a simple property, and also I've

What can be wrong?

Update:

This is how it's used in other components, say for example, list of employees:

```
<table id='employeesList'>
    <!-- showing the list here -->
</table>
<paging [(listOptions)]="listOptions"></paging>
```

`listOptions` has these properties: `pageNumber`, `pageSize`, `sorts` which is an array, and `filters` which is an array too.

Comment: What should change in the child component? Please give more detail

Comment: @echonax, in child component we have `<span>{{ listOptions.pageNumber }}</span>` for example. It shows nothing.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati how can we know what's wrong if you don't include the details ? :-) Is paging component the child or the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Input` should have the same name as you wrote in template

**parent template**

```
<paging [(listOptions)]="listOptions"></paging>
```

**paging.component.js**

```
inputs: ['listOptions']
```

To have two-way binding you need to have `listOptionsChange` output in `Paging` component

**[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/31xjbUShn6MzXfAs46kh?p=preview)**